# pandas percentage change with missing data

Tags: python, pandas, division, percentage

I need to get percentage change of multiple columns.

```
import pandas as pd
t="""Year\tChild\tBehaviour
1987\tBoy\tGood
1987\tGirl\tGood
1987\tBoy\tBad
1987\tGirl\tBad
2020\tBoy\tBad
2020\tBoy\tBad
2020\tGirl\tBad
2020\tGirl\tBad"""
from io import StringIO
df=pd.read_table(StringIO(t))
pv=pd.crosstab(df["Child"], [df["Year"], df["Behaviour"]])
print(pv)
print(pv[2020]/pv[1987]-1)
```

In the cruel world of the future there're no more good children, and it's a problem cause i get `NaN` instead of `-1` (-100%):

```
Year      1987      2020
Behaviour  Bad Good  Bad
Child                   
Boy          1    1    2
Girl         1    1    2

Behaviour  Bad  Good
Child               
Boy          1   NaN
Girl         1   NaN
```

How can this be solved in general case? Do i need to append missing columns filled by 0s beforehand? Or there's another way to get percentage change

Comment: The easiest is probably to ensure you have a column 'Good' with zeros for that year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this, using [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method?

```
>>> (pv[2020]/pv[1987]).fillna(0) - 1
Behaviour  Bad  Good
Child               
Boy          1    -1
Girl         1    -1
```

Other way would be use `dropna=True` parameter from [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) function:

```
>>> pv = pd.crosstab(df["Child"], [df["Year"], df["Behaviour"]], dropna=False)
>>> pv
      1987      2020     
       Bad Good  Bad Good
Child                    
Boy      1    1    2    0
Girl     1    1    2    0

>>> pv[2020]/pv[1987] - 1
       Bad  Good
Child           
Boy      1    -1
Girl     1    -1
```

Comment: thanks, i couldn't figure out how `dropna` argument affects result.

Comment: `dropna=False` drops columns level names for some reason. Looks like a bug.